# How to check DTD using libxml in C?

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

I'm working on a XML based chat and sending xml text via sockets. I'm not sure on how to validate with libxml using a DTD stored on server side (I want to check if the client sends a well formed xml message)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [libxml page](http://xmlsoft.org/xmldtd.html#validate) about validation, with links to the [appropriate api](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-valid.html).  The source to the [xmllint](http://opensource.apple.com/source/libxml2/libxml2-4/libxml2/xmllint.c) program may also be helpful.

Having said that, keep in mind [Postel's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle).